# How to load weather api data in c# and inject the class into _Layout

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I'm trying to fetch openweatherapi data and return this data as object, so later in _Layout I can inject this class and use this object. However, in _Layout I can't access to object properties.

```
public Weather WeatherApiResult()
{
    Weather weather = null;
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
       {
           string city = Weather();
           string apiKey = "KEY";
           string URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=" + apiKey;

           var httpClient = new HttpClient();
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("apiKey", $"{apiKey}");

           var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{URL}");
           var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(response);
       
       });
    return weather;

}
```

_Layout:

```
    @{
        var weather = settingsService.WeatherApiResult();

        weather.name
    }
```

Update:

```
@{
    var response = settingsService.WeatherApiResult();
    var name = response.Result.name;
    var timezone = response.Result.timezone;
    <p>@name</p>
    <p>@timezone</p>
}
```

It looks like I can access only the first-level properties `name`, `timezone`, `id`, `cod`.  How can I access the nested properties?
In JavaScript I would do response.main.temp for temperature. Do I need to create a Class for each nested item?

[image]

Comment: On which line exactly are you getting the error and what is the error message?

Comment: _Layout  : weather.name | CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: Don't use Task.Factory.StartNew. There's no point in a web application. Just await your method calls that return a Task or Task<T>, and mark your action method as async and have it return a Task<Weather>.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, I have tagged your question with the appropriate ASP.NET Core MVC framework.

Comment: Which nested properties are you unable to access? Please share the definition of your `Weather` class as well. And in case the json response you are getting from your api request has nested json objects then sure, you have to create more classes for your json to be correctly converted into C#

Comment: In that case, I have to create more classes. It was akward for me to add one class and all nested properties to be ok.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: If your json has nested objects then of course you have to create more classes, an alternate would be use linq and anonymous types to avoid creating more classes but I would suggest against it as it would increase code clutter and reduce code readability. And I really do not understand why adding another class or classes would be awkward for you. @Adam

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to use view components

Inside of Shared folder you have to crate a Components folder and then _Weather folder. Create the partial view _Weather.cshtml there

```
@model Weather

<div>
        
....    your html here like   

  <p>@Model.name</p>
    <p>@Model.timezone</p>
</div>
```

Create class in a Controllers folder

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "_Weather")]
public class _WeatherViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
//or
//public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
 Weather weather = null;
  string city = Weather();
   string apiKey = "KEY";
..... continue your code
return View("_Weather", weather);
}
```

_Layout

```
<div> @(await Component.InvokeAsync("_Weather")) </div>
```

another way is to creage a BaseModel class with Weather property and each view model should use BaseModel as a base class. And  each time you should download and assign data to the Weather property.

And you can also use your settingsService if you need

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "_Weather")]
public class _WeatherViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
     private readonly SettingsService _settingsService;

    public _WeatherViewComponent(SettingsService settingsService)
    {
      _settingService = settingsService;
    }

   
  public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
   {
   var weather = _settingsService.WeatherApiResult();
   return View("_Weather", weather);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through additional added details on your question, I am adding another answer which I think should solve your problem. Your actual problem is that you are unable to correctly convert the ApiResponse to C# class object because I am assuming that your C# class is not structured correctly. Create an `ApiResponseModel` class or name it anything you like, this class would be equal to your entire Api response. It should look something like this:-

```
namespace Your.NameSpace
{
    public class ApiResponseModel      //this class will have the base level properties
    {
        public Coord coord { get; set; }

        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }    //weather is a list because your ApiResponse has an array of Weather objects

        public Main main { get; set; }

        public Wind wind { get; set; }

        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Coord
    {
        public decimal lon { get; set; }

        public decimal lat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string main { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }

        public string icon { get; set; }
    }
    //similarly add more classes below to be able to correctly convert your json to C# if other properties are required to you.
}
```

Similar to how I have added classes above, you need to add a class for each nested json object.