# Partial view in NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i am lost with NET6.
I created this partial view _MenuNav.cshtml :

```
@model IEnumerable<CateringMilano.Models.Menu>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <a alt="@item.MenuTitle)">@item.MenuName</a>
        <b>@item.MenuTitle</b>
    </div>
}
```

and the cod in my controller is :

```
// GET: /Menus/_MenuNav/
        public ActionResult _MenuNav(string menuPosition)
        {
            // Get my db
            var model = _context.Menu.Include(m => m.ChildMenuSub) as IQueryable<Menu>;
            model = model.Where(p => p.MenuPosition == menuPosition);    
// Send your collection of Mreations to the View
 return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in the last project with net 4 i use to write the following code in the principal view in order to call my partial view :

```
@Html.Action("_MenuNav", "Menus", new { menuPosition = "Menu" })
```

but it looks like it does not work anymore this with NET6

Do you know how to rewrite my code in order to get the same result?

Comment: Regarding your concern please have look the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0#synchronous-html-helper). You might need to use view component in your scenario.

Comment: Hello do still have concern on this issue? Was the problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

you must be mixing view components with partial views. Partial view were always used like this

```
<div id="partialName">
<partial name="_PartialName" />
</div>
```

with model

```
<partial name="_PartialName" model="Model.MyInfo" />
```

or for async

```
<div id="partialName">
@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")
</div>
```

and the most popular way to update parital view is using ajax

And you can check my answer about viewcomponents here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69698058/11392290

Comment: Hi Serge, but i do not wanto to update via ajax.. i just want a simple partial view and be able to pass a string or id from the principal view to the partial view... so, how to implement this : @await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName")

Comment: @You can not do this,  you can only create  main view  that includes partial views , and this partial view can get data from main view model.  And your action should return the whole view if you don't want to use an ajax. Otherwise you have to create a view component instead.

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks again for your reponse. how can i create a view component? i just need to show a list of records that have the id of the showed page, example : page of article 3501 (table ARTICLES), show a partial view of list of differents description (table ARTICLESDESCRIPTIONS). any example to accomplish this by passing an ID to the partial view?

Comment: Hi, anything easier than this?

Comment: @TamilCantroz check my answer about viewcomponents here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69698058/11392290

Comment: Hi serge, have you got something more similar to my example?

Answer (score 0):

In Dot Net 6 "RenderAction" was replaced with "View Component" and is supposed to offer people who don't want to call Back-End Controller Action's via the Front End (AJAX) an option to do so (AJAX is not *THE* solution, it's *A* Solution). I'm presently working through a similar problem myself and AJAX is not an option available to me due to an internal restriction. With that said, This [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is proving to be a valuable resource for me.

In essence, on creates a Class similar to a Controller, except its name is appended with "ViewComponent" instead of "Controller" (e.g. NameOfViewComponent vs NameOfController) these then provide return values for a Partial View.

That said, this is a work in progress for me. If you find anything pertaining to this method I'd be very interested to hear it.